# Centralize Toolbar Text View

Tags: android, toolbar

[image]When I am setting `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);`
My text view in toolbar is not displaying in center,because menu icon is active,so how can I centralize it?

**Toolbar layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   android:id="@+id/toolbar"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
   android:background="@android:color/white"
   android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
   app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
   app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
   app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/centerTitleToolbarTextView"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:gravity="center"
       android:maxLines="1"
       android:textColor="@color/color_toolbar"
       android:textSize="@dimen/titleToolbar" />

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

**Toolbar setUp in Activity**

```
protected void initToolbar() {
       toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
       toolbar.setContentInsetsAbsolute(0, 0);
       setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
       getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
       getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
       toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View view) {
               onBackPressed();
           }
       });
       toolbarTextView = (TextView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.centerTitleToolbarTextView);

   }
```

Comment: can you please show us the view. Screenshot?

Comment: use custom design and set it as toolbar

Answer (score 3):

Try this

In your Activity, in your `onCreate()` method:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM); 
getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.abs_layout);
```

`action_layout`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="my Title"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:id="@+id/mytext"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Now you should have an `Actionbar` with just a title. If you want to set a custom background, set it in the Layout above (but then don't forget to set `android:layout_height="match_parent"`).

or with:

```
getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.yourimage));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your textview

```
 android:layout_gravity="center"
```

Comment: It is not possible if your parent view is toolbar

Comment: @ArmanManucharyan Remove `android:gravity="center"` from Your TextView and make width to `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` like my above ans